# select less than and replace with value in column A

Tags: excel-2010

I have a table with a few thousand rows and columns, it looks sort of like this
this:

```
ID         Distance1   Distance2
1          102         101
2          101         100
3          100         99
4          99          98
5          98          97
...
```

I would like to select all values/distances in columns `B` and `C` that are less than **100** and replace them with the value in column `A` (their *ID number*).

All distances above **100** I want to delete. The real table has several thousand columns. How can I do this?

I have tried using search and replace, and conditional formatting where I have tried creating new rule using Index + Match but I encounter errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ID` is in A1 of Sheet1, Copy the headings row into A1 of a new sheet and in B2 of that sheet:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!B2<100,Sheet1!B2>0),Sheet1!$A2,"")
```

Copy across and down to suit, Select the new sheet, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.

This above treats `100` as more than `100` and assumes no `0` or lesser values.